# signal/Textsecure bindings for c/c++?

Tags: c++, messaging

I am trying to create a signal/textsecure client using qt and C++, however i cant seem to fibd any C++ bindings for it.

the only bindings i can find are for Go (https://github.com/nanu-c/textsecure/)

is there any way to connect C++ with signal?

edit:
i wanted to clarify some things:

-im talking about the messaging app called Signal (https://signal.org)

-i am trying to write an app for ubuntu touch and am developing on manjaro linux.

Comment: **This is operating system specific.** On Linux and on Windows (and probably on MacOSX or iOS too), a Qt process can co-exist and communicate with a process running some program written in Go. Your question needs to be [edited](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61230626/edit) and you should **provide *a lot more* details**, including some [MRE]

Comment: Regarding Unix signals and Qt5, see [this](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/unix-signals.html)

Comment: Be aware of [Inter-process communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) facilities. They are obviously operating system specific. On Linux see [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html) and [socket(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html)

Comment: Give at least the URL of your `signal` application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after a little more digging i found that textsecure bindings are now renamed to libsignal.

after finding that out i found a lib for c/c++
https://github.com/signalapp/libsignal-protocol-c

Answer (score 0):

On Linux or Unix, you probably want to communicate with other remote applications using some communication protocol, such as [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) or [HTTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS) or [SOAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP) or  [JSONRPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON-RPC) or [ONCRPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Network_Computing_Remote_Procedure_Call). Of course read about [socket(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html) and before that [Advanced Linux Programming](http://www.makelinux.net/alp/) then about [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html). Consider reading a textbook on [*Operating Systems*](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~remzi/OSTEP/)

Be sure to study the [source code related to Signal](https://github.com/signalapp). Read their [technical documentation](https://www.signal.org/docs/).

You surely need to understand the details. So take a few days or weeks to read more about them.

If you want to use some [web service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service), you need to read and understand its documentation and when and how you are allowed to use it. There could be legal or financial issues.

Then you might use HTTP related libraries (e.g. [Wt](https://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt) or [libonion](http://www.coralbits.com/libonion) server side, and [libcurl](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) or [curlpp](https://www.curlpp.org/) client side).

See also in April 2020 the ongoing [HelpCovid](https://github.com/bstarynk/helpcovid/) [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) project (for Linux), at least for inspiration. We are coding it in C++.